# Trying to put a matrix in the graphic console

Tags: c, matrix

I created a random matrix and now I'm trying to use the graphic_text function to put it on the graphic console i have this code here but its not working, how can i make this work? The main objective of this code is creating a memory game so the numbers from the matrix must stay inside of the circles that i created. I read something about covert my int matrix int a char but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pg/graphics.h"


#define MaxC 4
#define MaxL 5


void background (void)
  {
    graph_rect(0,0,400,480,graph_rgb(102,51,0),true);
    graph_rect(420,390,190,40,c_black,true);    
  }

void tabuleiro (void)
  {
    int n,k;
    for (k=0; k<5; k++) {
       for (n=0; n<4; n++){

           graph_circle (50+(95*n), 410-(90*k), 40, c_black,true);
                        }
                          }

graph_text(430,422,graph_rgb(255,255,255), "Novo Jogo", LARGE_FONT);

}

 void gerar_matriz(void){

    int na[10] = {0};
    int i=0,j=0,r;
    int n[MaxL][MaxC];
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(i<5){
        j=0;
       while(j<4){
         r=(rand()%10);

         if(na[r]<2){
            na[r]++;
            j++;
            n[i][j]=r;
            printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
        }
    }
    i++;
    printf("\n");

    }
}

void matriz_grafica(void){
      char n[MaxL][MaxC];
    gerar_matriz();

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
          char b= n[i][j];
          graph_text(50+(95*j), 410-(90*i), graph_rgb(255,255,255),b,LARGE_FONT);
    }
 }

 }

void restart(void)
 {
  graph_rect(0,0,GRAPH_WIDTH,GRAPH_HEIGHT, graph_rgb(250,250,250),true);
  graph_rect(0,0,320,480,graph_rgb(102,51,0),true);
  background();
  tabuleiro();
  gerar_matriz();
 }  


void myMouseEventHandler (MouseEvent mouse){

if(mouse.state==BUTTON_CLICK && mouse.button==BUTTON_LEFT){
  if (mouse.x<610 && mouse.x>420 && mouse.y<430 && mouse.y>390 )       
  {
    restart();
  }
}

}


int main (){

srand(time(NULL));
graph_init();
background();
tabuleiro();
gerar_matriz();
graph_regist_mouse_handler(myMouseEventHandler);
graph_start () ;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code so it will include indentation

Comment: `char a={b,0};` is certainly strange. Or I'm missing something. char on the left, array on the right.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think i forgot to delet that